# C# constructor not being called within STAThread?

Tags: c#, multithreading, xunit

I'm creating an API to interact with a basic home router. In this case the only way this is possible is with a WebBrowser object. I put that object in a BrowserWrapper class to hide most of the complexity.

Here is my XUnit `[Fact]` for retrieving the SSID.

```
[Fact]
public void GetSsid()
{
   RouterApi api = new RouterApi();
   string ssid = api.GetSsid();
   Assert.NotNull(ssid);
}
```

Constructor for RouterApi

```
private BrowserWrapper browserWrapper;

public RouterApi()
{
   try
   {
      browserWrapper = new BrowserWrapper();

      Thread browserThread = new Thread(() => { Application.Run(browserWrapper); });
      browserThread.SetApartmentState(ApartmentState.STA);
      browserThread.Start();
   }
   catch (Exception ex) { //Handle ex }
}
```

I know the BrowserWrapper constructor isn't being called because in the constructor for BrowserWrapper I instantiate a bunch of things (one of them is the `WebBrowser` control), and they're still null when I try to interact with them in `api.GetSsid()`. (Note: I'm using delegate methods to interact with my BrowserWrapper from my RouterApi.)

I know this all works because I've already written an API almost exactly this way, but this is my first time using XUnit, so I think the problem lies there.

Comment: The constructor is called *before* you start the thread.  That's not what you want.  Use [code like this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4271581/17034).

Comment: So I should move where I instantiate BrowserWrapper? BrowserWrapper isn't my WebBrowser, it just contains one.